# Reason behind the names of sub and supercritical bifurcations

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, terminology, bifurcation

What is the reasoning behind the names sub- and super-critical bifurcations that occur in the context of pitchfork and Hopf bifurcations? Textbooks seem to introduce this terminology without any explanation as to why.

In one place it is said that "supercritical" means "fixed points are created after the critical point." However, "before" and "after" depends on the meaning of the control parameter, and switching from say, $r$ to $−r$ changes this meaning. Hence this explanation seems to be weak at best.